# Keep highcharts y-axis labels in view

Tags: css, highcharts

I'm trying to apply fixed positioning to the labels on my y-axis so that if the user scrolls to the right of the graph, they're still visible.  Alternatively, labeling the grid lines every so often would also work, but I can't find a way to do that either.  I've tried the code below as well as trying to target it in the accompanying CSS file (preferred, as I'm trying to make it responsive.

```
  yAxis: {

        gridZIndex: 7,
        gridLineColor: '#666',
        gridLineDashStyle: 'Dash',

        labels: {
            attr: {
                position: 'fixed',
                left: '10px'

            },
            css: {
                position: 'fixed',
                left: '10px'
            }
        }
    },
```

EDIT:

So if the entire graph is not viewable all at once, you can only see the y-axis when all the way to the left.  I'd like the grid lines to be labeled or for the y-axis to be a fixed location.

Good:

[image: Good]

Not so good (no way to see y-axis values when scrolled over a bit to the right):

[image]

Comment: can you post an example? not understanding the problem or the desired result.

Comment: The panning feature seems to do what I'd like, but I can only get that to work if I also enable zoom, which I don't want.

Comment: A working example would be much easier. I guess the real question I'm unclear on is how are you accomplishing the scrolling? There are a number of examples out there of scrolling the data while keeping the whole chart (and there for the axes) fully visible.

Comment: It's on a mobile device so it's just larger than the window.  The only option I found was panning but I couldn't get it to work.  If you have any other ideas of possible solutions I could investigate that would be helpful.

Comment: Try to use highstock.js if it will not work panning option, recreate it as live demo.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/4gk4zmgh/

Uses panning:true, no zoom enabled.

You can set the axis extremes programmatically after the chart loads, which will allow you to pan without the zoom functionality being present.
ie:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0,5);
```